# Display icon on D3 planet canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js

I'm doing some stuff along the lines of this sample code of a rotating planet using D3.js:

http://rveciana.github.io/geoexamples/?page=d3js/d3js_svgcanvas/rotatingCanvas.html

The problem is that I haven't been able to figure out how to draw an image on the globe at a specific longitude-latitude. Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is not very specific, but I guess that the [Raster Reprojection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4329423) demo can help. Using the same technique with a different image (and projection) should do the trick.

Comment: To be more specific I want to draw an icon at a specific point to mark that location.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this? Is an interesting problem, but it would take some time to setup the fiddle myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the tutoria: [Let’s Make a Bubble Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/).

Instead of drawing the bubbles, you can add the icon you prefer.